# Custom Class in a script?

Tags: powershell, class

Haven't coded in PowerShell in a few years and have a need to create a custom class.  Poked through the docs and a few blogs and custom classes seemed simple enough, but I get the following error whenever I try to load even a simple class from a script.

I've tried running a test script and dot sourcing the file with the class:

```
The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
At C:\Temp\test.ps1:1 char:1
+ . ./classtest.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], FileLoadException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException
```

Calling the file with the class directly throws the same error:

```
The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
At line:1 char:1
+ .\classtest.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], FileLoadException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException
```

I scrapped my entire class and just grabbed a super simple example online as follows(this is what's currently in classtest.ps1 in the above errors):

```
class student {
    [string]$FirstName
    [string]$LastName
}
```

If I paste that class into a running PowerShell window, it works just fine.  If I put it in a file and try to run it I get the same errors above whether calling the file directly or attempting to dot source the file into another script.

There's got to be something stupidly simple that I am missing here, how does one use a class in a PowerShell script?

Comment: Are you using the same class name (`Student`) from the one that trowed that error?

Comment: I'm not even using the class.  I literally have a ps1 file with just the class definition in it, and nothing else, not even comments, and it throws that error when I run the script.  I would just expect it to run and do nothing, not throw an error.

Comment: I'm personally not able to reproduce tho I'm using PS Core. This might be an issue on Win PS?

Comment: Don't have core, so it could be Windows PS specific.  Though I thought the only real difference was core was cross platform compatible, but either way yes, I am running the standard Windows PowerShell.  5.1 Build 19041 Revision 1320

Comment: Believe it's part of your sessions constrained language mode.

Comment: I'm assuming you have tried restarting your PS session and the same issue occurs on PS CLI and PS ISE?

Comment: Yes, killed all open PS windows, reopened.  Tried the IDE.  Discovered I have PowerShell for VS 2019 on my machine, tried that too.  Same error on all of them.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be constrained language mode.  This is a corporate machine so I don't get to control this stuff but the output of $ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode = FullLanguage

Comment: This might seem odd, but could you create a function like `New-Student` which does something like `[Student]::new(...)`, and then try to load that module? From what I know, `ps` is a pain when dealing with classes from other files.

Comment: yeah figured it out.  will share the answer in a second.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  Apparently custom class libraries are touchy in PowerShell.  Had to save it off to just standard text file, then load that file with `Invoke-Expression` to load it into my PowerShell script.  After that I could use it exactly how I would expect it to work.

```
Invoke-Expression $([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('C:\Temp\myclass.txt'))
$NewStudent = [student]::new()
$NewStudent.FirstName = "bob"
$NewStudent.LastName = "Johson"
$NewStudent
```

A bit annoying, but it works.

Comment: Indeed a bit odd, I was unable to replicate the error even in WinPS

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what [Vivere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70897887/custom-class-in-a-script#comment125338695_70897887) commented and that you need to add constructor(s) to the class like:

```
class student {
    [string]$FirstName
    [string]$LastName

    # create an empty student object
    student () {}

    # overload to create a student object with just the firstname
    student ([string]$FirstName) {
        $this.FirstName = $FirstName
    }

    # overload to create a student object with both first and lastname
    student ([string]$FirstName, [string]$LastName) {
        $this.FirstName = $FirstName
        $this.LastName  = $LastName
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
$student1 = [student]::new()
$student2 = [student]::new('Name1')
$student3 = [student]::new('Someone', 'Else')
```

Comment: From a class perspective yes, that is a better way to write a class.  But that still doesn't solve the problem of having a custom class in a script.  Only way I have found to make that work, with your example or otherwise, is by using the invoke-expression line in my answer to this below.   That stupidly simple class I was using was just a simple example to illustrate the problem, your class above throws the same error.

Comment: @user3246693 Sorry, but I can only imagine your problem has to do with to the file encoding you use to save the ps1 file then.. Did you check the encoding of the problematic .ps1 file as opposed to the same file when saved with notepad?